# Who's the last person on the "Others of Note" codex list?

Tags: hades

In Hades, the codex features info on each character you can meet, separated into lists based on their affiliation. However, in the other people of note session, there's one name that's still ????, despite me having beaten the final boss a good eight or nine times by now.

Who is this final person? And how do I meet them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Persephone. After the credits play, she'll appear in the codex.